# Bringing in UTM content and term into a big query search

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've got a query now that pulls in source, mediu, and campaign, as they're in my schema, however I'm now looking to pull in utm_content and utm_term as well, but they're not in my schema.
Is there a way that I can pull in those two utm parameters from the URL, and add them to my query, so that it pulls everything?

```
    SELECT 
    event_name, 
    event_date, 
    traffic_source.medium, 
    traffic_source.name, 
    traffic_source.source,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(traffic_source.medium, traffic_source.source)) AS event_count, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN ep.key = 'sr_posting_id' THEN ep.value.int_value ELSE NULL END) AS sr_posting_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ep.key = 'page_title' THEN ep.value.string_value ELSE NULL END) AS page_title
    FROM 
   `nth-glider-369017.analytics_316822874.events_*` e 
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(event_params) AS ep
    WHERE 
    event_name IN ("sr_job_application_started", "sr_job_application_continued",             
    "sr_job_completed_application")
    GROUP BY 
    event_name, 
    event_date, 
    traffic_source.medium, 
    traffic_source.name, 
    traffic_source.source,
```

`
I'm not really sure how to do it, as I can't edit the schema can I?

Comment: I may be wrong but the SQL you've provided doesn't seem to be valid. You're selecting from 2 sources that you've aliased as 'e' and 'ep' but then you are referencing columns with 'traffic_source'. Also, please update your question with the DDL tables involved. Your question talks about two additional columns (utm_content and utm_term) but you've given no information about what these are, where they are coming from etc. - don't assume knowledge about your data on the part of someone reading your question